# c# maximizar aplicacion sin ocultar la barra de tareas winforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, windows

Hola estoy desarrollando una aplicación Windows con C# y deseo que al maximizar el winforms 
pero al utilizar :

`WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;`

me oculta la barra de tareas, tengo la propiedad de `FormBorderStyle = None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

por si le sirve a alguien buscando encontre varias formas de solucionarlo pero la mas facil y con menos lineas es esta:
Colocar este codigo en el evento load del Form

```
 this.MaximumSize = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorMaximizedWindowSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

con el metodo Screen obtines las pantallas que tienes, y seleccionamos la primaria que seria la del computador en caso de ser proyector o extendida ya seria pantalla secundaria, y con working area selecionamos solo el area que se puede trabajar sin la barra de tareas, asi le podria poner un maximumSize a tu formulario al cargarlo, por ejemplo podrias meter el siguiente codigo en el evento load del formulario.

```
    private void RegistrarUsuario_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ancho=Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
        int alto=Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
        
        this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(ancho, alto);
    }
```